# How do I require modules whose names are unknown at compile time?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, systemjs, jspm, webpack-2

I have a React web app which loads an app skeleton.
After the skeleton is loaded in the browser, it gets a list of module names from the server by ajax.
Then, it needs to fetch these module names from the server, and load them as react components inside the skeleton.

I started with Webpack 1 and had troubles loading dynamic modules because require.ensure() needs to figure out the names at build time.

I moved to JSPM where loading dynamic modules worked, but created other issues in the project.

I want to move back to Webpack but I don't know how to achieve dynamic component bundle loading.

Maybe use Webpack2?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get this working using Webpack 2.

There are examples that show how to use ReactRouter and Webpack 2, and load each route dynamically.

Used the following links:

- [Code splitting using React and Webpack 2](http://moduscreate.com/code-splitting-for-react-router-with-es6-imports/)
- [Migrating from Webpack 1 to Webpack 2](http://moduscreate.com/webpack-2-tree-shaking-configuration/)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may be able to achieve this using webpack [Code Splitting](https://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html).

> Code Splitting can be used to split code into an on demand loaded
>   chunk. This can keep the initial download small and downloads code on
>   demand when requested by the application.

Comment: The link you provided points to Webpack 1 documentation.

Code splitting in Webpack 1 doesn't solve this, since it does not support loading of modules whose names are unknown at build time.

Comment: Oh, good call. I didn't notice a version on the docs. Glad you found a solution.